# Why is the newline char in my regex matching an entire line?

Tags: regex

As I understood it the regex

```
^1.*\n
```

should match a line beginning with 1 followed by any number of characters and a newline char, then stop.  What it actually does when using Perl regex is match a line beginning with 1 followed by any number of characters and a newline char **and then the whole of the following line**:

```
-bash-3.2$ cat testfile
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
3   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
3   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
3   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd

-bash-3.2$ grep -P '^1.*' testfile
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
-bash-3.2$ grep -P '^1.*\n' testfile
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
1   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
2   dghdfgdgdgdfgdfggd
```

I was actually working on a longer multi-line pattern and wondering why it didn't work, and tracked it down to the above issue.  My question is mostly "why is it behaving this way", but I'm happy to hear ways to get the match I wanted.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to pass `-oP` options? `grep -oP '^1.*\n' testfile`. [*`--only-matching` - 
Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.*](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` outputs matched *lines*. To override that behavior, pass the `-o` option.

```
grep -oP '^1.*\n' testfile`.
```

See the [`grep` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> `-o`
>     `--only-matching`
>       *Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.*

Comment: <embarrassed face> I knew that!  What a numpty.  Thanks :)